# Lua Gideros: Draw Line with touch

Tags: android, graphics, lua, gideros

In my game using Lua and Gideros studio, I want someone to be able to draw a straight line with touch by making the beginning of the line where they touched the screen, and the end of the line where they released. When I run my code (below) I always get this message:

*main.lua:66: attempt to index global 'event' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    main.lua:66: in main chunk*

Here is my code:

```
local function onMouseDown(event)
    event.x = startx
    event.y = starty

    event:stopPropagation()
end

local function onMouseUp(event)
    event.x = endx
    event.y = endy
    event:stopPropagation()
    local line = Shape.new()
    line:setLineStyle(5, 0x0000ff, 1)
    line:beginPath()
    line:moveTo(startx,starty)
    line:lineTo(endx,endy)
    line:endPath()

end
```

This next line is line 66 in my code:

```
scene:addEventListener(event.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown)
scene:addEventListener(event.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUp)
```

Anybody know why this is happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because it is `Event.MOUSE_DOWN`, Lua is case sensitive.

Comment: I did that, and it fixed that problem. Now it is saying:                main.lua:66: index '__userdata' cannot be found
stack traceback:
 main.lua:66: in main chunk

Comment: open a new question with the proper information such as full stack trace message, and show the "scene = " line so we can check how you created the scene

Comment: Here is a link to my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26110692/lua-gideros-touble-drawing-line-with-touch     (BTW I would post screenshot but I don't have enough reputation. Sorry!)