# Lua Gideros: Trouble drawing line with touch

Tags: android, graphics, lua, gideros

In my Game using Gideros and Lua, I want players to be able to draw a straight line from the point they touch the screen until the point they release. However, when I try run this code, I always get an error message. Here is the code:

```
local function onMouseDown(event)
    event.x = startx
    event.y = starty

    event:stopPropagation()
end

local function onMouseUp(event)
    event.x = endx
    event.y = endy
    event:stopPropagation()
    local line = Shape.new()
    line:setLineStyle(5, 0x0000ff, 1)
    line:beginPath()
    line:moveTo(startx,starty)
    line:lineTo(endx,endy)
    line:endPath()

end
```

This next line is line 66 in my code:

```
scene:addEventListener(Event.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown)
scene:addEventListener(Event.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUp)
```

Here is the line where I set up "scene":

```
scene = gideros.class(Sprite)
```

Here is my error message:

main.lua:66: index '__userdata' cannot be found
stack traceback:
    main.lua:66: in main chunk

Does anyone know why I am getting this message?

Comment: Where is line 66 in your code?

Comment: I added this to my question just now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do

```
scene = gideros.class(Sprite)
```

it means scene is a class, but you can add event listeners only to the instance of the class, not the class itself.

So something like this should work:

```
Scene = gideros.class(Sprite)
local scene = Scene.new()
stage:addChild(scene)
```

Comment: I did that, now when I release my finger from the screen, it says:  main.lua:62: bad argument #1 to 'moveTo' (number expected, got nil)
stack traceback:
 main.lua:62: in function <main.lua:55>

Comment: You are doing assignment in wrong direction, it should be `startx = event.x` , etc

Comment: Thanks! That worked well! Here is part 2 of my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26370334/lua-gideros-line-with-touch-2      Maybe you could answer!